# How to programmatically find install location of an installed application in Windows

Tags: windows, installation, windows-installer, uninstallation

I want to find the installed location for an MSI based installation programmatically. The app does not make an entry of Install Location in the uninstall key in the registry. Application does not populate ARPINSTALLLOCATION property. (This is the same value that is referred by Add/Remove Program and is stored in Uninstall key).  However uninstall still finds where it is located and can uninstall it. Where is this information stored? Windows uses a cached MSI installer for uninstalling the application however Install Location is determined for the first time while installing so this information is not part of the installer package.

Answer (score 2):

I assume when you say "install location", you really mean "what directory is the EXE of the application located at?"  Otherwise, the question is ambiguous because an MSI doesn't necessarily have to install an "application".  It could install a component that has no EXE.  And it can install it across multiple directories...

But this will likely work:

Call [MsiGetProductInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370130%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)  to get the ARPINSTALLLOCATION.  You will need to know the "product name" as it is installed by. to as the first param.  Call [MsiEnumProducts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370101%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to enumerate all the installed "products" if needed

Comment: Related to this, when you know it's an .msi and can find a component within it, you can use MsiGetComponentPath (or MsiLocateComponent) to locate its keypath. This will likely be the exe for the right component.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a VBScript version that uses the `WindowsInstaller.Installer` COM interface:

```vb
Dim installer
Set installer = CreateObject("WindowsInstaller.Installer")
Dim productCode, productName
For Each productCode In installer.Products
    WScript.Echo "ProductCode: " & productCode
    WScript.Echo "ProductName: " & installer.ProductInfo(productCode, "ProductName")
    WScript.Echo "InstallLocation: " & installer.ProductInfo(productCode, "InstallLocation")
    WScript.Echo "LocalPackage: " & installer.ProductInfo(productCode, "LocalPackage")
Next
```

Find out more about the Installer object from [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369432(v=vs.85).aspx#methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369432%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#methods)